# Unable to save resume file. Too many open files

Tags: 12.04, filesystem, transmission

Every time i am getting `Unable to save resume file. Too many open files error` in transmission application. I got solution in [this](http://blog.samat.org/2011/04/05/Increase-file-descriptors-for-Transmission-on-Linux) post.

```
sudo sh -c "echo fs.file-max=$(dc -e '2 20 ^ p') > /etc/sysctl.d/file-descriptors-max.conf"
sudo service procps restart
```

But sudo service procps restart output:

```
stop: Unknown instance: 
procps stop/waiting
```

Can anyone please help me out? I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

My current Ubuntu 12.04 installation shows 98930 as value for `file-max`

```
> cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
98930
```

If you want to raise this value, you have several options.

1. Create a new file: `echo "fs.file-max=$(dc -e '2 20 ^ p')" | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/60-file-descriptors-max.conf`. This command writes the echoed line into the file. If the file exists it is silently overwritten. According to the documentation you should choose the value `60-*.conf` for user values. After you have done this you should enter `sudo service procps start` and not `restart` like in your example. As you can see with the command `sudo service procps status` the program is not running.
2. Directly write into the file in the proc filesystem: `echo $(dc -e '2 20 ^ p') | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/file-max`. After the command the value is set and will be used. You can use the above mentioned `cat` command to get the current value.